# ContainerD nodes in GKE based on Windows

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, windows-container, containerd

Is there a tutorial, manual, or instructions on how to get started using ContainerD as a primary tool to build images for K8S (on Windows) since Google Kubernetes is abandoning Docker-based Windows nodes and recommending switching to ContainerD nodes?

P.S. I mean full cycle: For example I have ASP .NET Framework 4.5 web application - what are my steps to actually run it on GKE Windows based cluster with ContainerD ?

Answer (score 2):

The switch to containerd should have no impact to how you build and publish your container images. So the steps would be identical and you don't need to do anything different. The only thing that's different is the image type of the nodepool when you create a new nodepool or cluster. Here are the steps for how to create a GKE windows cluster (also mentions containerd): https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster-windows#create_a_cluster_and_node_pools

Your deployment pod spec would point to the exact same container image like you were using with your docker based nodes.

Comment: I think that you are right - it seems that I always forget the part that it says that ContainerD is a **run-time**